# What the difference when declaring these variables in swift using ! or ()

Tags: ios, swift

What is  the difference of declaring variables this way?

```
var contacts: [Person]!
var contacts = [Person]()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `var contacts: [Person]!` you don't actually initialize a Person array.

```
var contacts: [Person]! // contacts still nil
var contacts = [Person]() // Person array with 0 objects
```

If you use `()` instead you initialize an empty `Person` array.

Answer (score 1):

Variable declarations in Swift take the following form:

```
var name: Type = initialValue
```

That is, you declare a variable called `name` of some `Type`, and set it to an `initialValue`.

There are many shorthand forms though, so you will see various alternatives.  The one you see the most often is leaving off the `Type` part.  If you do, then the type of `name` is “inferred” from the `initialValue`.

This is what is happening with `var contacts = [Person]()`.  The type is an `Array` of `Person`.  The `()` is calling the initializer (i.e. creating the array).

Alternatively, you can declare a variable, with a type, but not give it an initial value.  But the compiler won’t let you use it until you are guaranteed to have set it with an initial value. So for example, you could write `var contacts: [Person]`, then later `contacts = [Person]()`.

When you write `var contacts: [Person]!`, with a `!`, you are declaring a variable of type `Optional<[Person]>` – that is, a type that can either be `nil`, or contain an array.  Unlike regular arrays, optionals of arrays have a *default* value if you don’t initialize them.  The default value is `nil` – that is, that the optional does *not* contain an array.

But the `!` (instead of the more common `?`) means it is declared to be a special kind of optional, called an “implicitly-unwrapped optional” – that is, an optional that, when you use it in certain ways, will act as if it *isn’t* optional.  The big downside of this is that it will let you use it as if it isn’t an optional.  But if you do and it is `nil` then **your program will crash**.  So before anyone uses `contacts`, it will need to be initialized (such as with `contacts = [Person]()` or assigning some existing array to it)

For this reason, it’s best to not use these implicitly-unwrapped optionals except in very specific circumstances.  They sometimes seem like they’re convenient but they’re usually not the best option as they’re dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

The operator : is not declaring, its just saying which type a variable is

Operator = is as in every other language a declaring operator which in this case followed by the () which in this case declared a new array of Person.

Comment: "Operator = is...a declaring operator” The `=` is not declaring anything.  It is assigning a value to the lhs. It’s `var` that is declaring.

Comment: Thats true, I need to practice my terminology

Answer (score 0):

Other people provided the differences, I'll give you the scenarios of when either should be used.

```
var contacts: [Person]! //implicitly unwrapped optional. #1
var contacts = [Person]() //array initialization. #2
```

I use #1 when I create a variable that won't be initialized by it's own class. This situation occurs when I implement a detail view that takes in information that is passed by another controller.

For #2, use when you want to initialized a new empty array.